# pandas cut function hangs

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using pandas 23.4. Was testing the `cut` function. I haven't used it before. My test:

```
x = [1.1e9, 1.4e9, 2.3e9, 3e9, 3.4e9, 4.4e9]
pd.cut(x, 1e9)
```

This hangs, python eventually kills it. I want it to cut evenly from 0 to 5e9 by 1e9.

Comment: `pd.cut(x, 1e9)` is trying to cut your list x into an array of 1,000,000,000 integers. That's going to take a while (on my laptop it takes no time, because I get a `MemoryError` instantly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC

```
pd.cut(pd.Series(x), bins=range(0,int(6e9),int(1e9)))
Out[392]: 
0    (1000000000, 2000000000]
1    (1000000000, 2000000000]
2    (2000000000, 3000000000]
3    (2000000000, 3000000000]
4    (3000000000, 4000000000]
5    (4000000000, 5000000000]
dtype: category
Categories (5, interval[int64]): [(0, 1000000000] < (1000000000, 2000000000] <
                                  (2000000000, 3000000000] < (3000000000, 4000000000] <
                                  (4000000000, 5000000000]]
```